# How to get boolean mask for padding

Tags: tensorflow, padding, mask

Using `tf.extract_image_patches` with padding `'SAME'` will result in some patches containing padding (that is fine).

Is there an easy way to get a TensorFlow boolean mask which masks all patches containing padding? Or will I need to reimplement the padding process?

Comment: Do you need to find indices of padded patches? Or you need pixelwise masks for padded (zero) values within patches?

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko  I only need the indices of padded patches

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add an additional channel that represents a bit flag.
After extracting the image patches the bit flag is `0` for a channel that is padding and `1` for a non padding channel.

Full solution:

```
input_tensor = tf.random.normal([10, 28, 28, 1])
window_shape, strides, padding = (4, 4), (2, 2), 'SAME'

# ----------------------------

bits = tf.ones([tf.shape(input_tensor)[0], input_tensor.shape[1], input_tensor.shape[2], 1])
input_for_patching = tf.concat([input_tensor, bits], axis=-1)

patches = tf.extract_image_patches(input_for_patching, ksizes=(1, *window_shape, 1), strides=(1, *strides, 1), rates=(1, 1, 1, 1), padding=padding)

patches_shape = patches.shape

patches = tf.reshape(patches, [-1, *window_shape, input_tensor.shape[3] + 1])

padding_mask = tf.to_float(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(patches[:, :, :, -1:], 1.0), [1, 2, 3]))

patches = tf.reshape(patches[:, :, :, :-1], [-1, patches_shape[1], patches_shape[2], window_shape[0] * window_shape[1] * input_tensor.shape[3]])
```

The `padding_mask` from the code above is what I needed.

If someone has a shorter, more elegant and / or more integrated version, please feel free to share.